# GCP Http Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-load-balancer

I have service running in one of my VM port `8088`, I want all traffic to be send to this port via my `HTTP LOAD BALANCER`

```
Load-Balancer-IP:8088 -> Redirect to my VM port 8088
Load-Balancer-IP-> Redirect to my VM port 8088
```

How to configure this in gcp load balancer setting currently my configuration look like this
[image]

Comment: What's your issue? What's your question?

Comment: How to configure load balancer to redirect all traffic to VM port 8088

Comment: It is not what you did? You redirect the port 80 to the port 8088 here no?

Comment: If I want to re direct my <LB Address>:8088, to my service vm at 8088 , how to configure that ?

Answer (score 0):

To forward a custom port to your backend, you need to use a [tcp load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp) in single region only.

[image]

[image]

Keep in mind that is not a proxy but a port forwarding and SSL certificate aren't managed on the load balancer. If you want to use one, you have to host and manage it on your VM.